# How to resolve a conflict between RFCs?

Tags: dns, rfc, mdns

[RFC 4034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034) and [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) appear to contradict one another.

RFC 4034 states the following:

> A sender **MUST NOT** use DNS name compression on the Next Domain Name field when transmitting an NSEC RR.

<sup>* emphasis mine</sup>

RFC 6762 states the following:

> All compliant Multicast DNS implementations MUST at least correctly generate and parse the restricted DNS NSEC record format described below:
>
> - The 'Next Domain Name' field contains the record's own name. When used with name compression, this means that the 'Next Domain Name' field always takes exactly two bytes in the message.

This appears to be a conflict. One RFC says that name compression should not be used and another suggests that compliant implementations must be able to generate and parse records with name compression.

Given that mDNS is designed to work correctly with existing DNS resolvers, how am I as a programmer supposed to implement methods for generating and parsing NSEC records?

Should I use name compression or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While mDNS borrows heavily from DNS, they are not the same protocol. There are numerous significant differences between them, and the use of `NSEC` records is one of them. Since DNSSEC doesn't make sense in an mDNS context (mDNS does not have delegation), mDNS appropriates the `NSEC` record type for its own use. Which is to replace the DNS `NXDOMAIN` functionality, like this (from RFC 6762 section 6.1):

> Any time a responder receives a query for a name for which it has
>   verified exclusive ownership, for a type for which that name has no
>   records, the responder MUST (except as allowed in (a) below) respond
>   asserting the nonexistence of that record using a DNS NSEC record
>   [RFC4034].  In the case of Multicast DNS the NSEC record is not being 
>   used for its usual DNSSEC [RFC4033] security properties, but simply
>   as a way of expressing which records do or do not exist with a given
>   name.

The reason that DNS `NSEC` records must not use name compression is that they must have exactly one well-defined binary representation that can be cryptographically signed. Allowing compression would mean that there were several different correct wireformat representations of the same content, which would be a problem when trying to verify a signature, since one could not be sure which representation was used when generating the signature.

mDNS does not sign things, so that restriction doesn't apply, so it is free to use name compression in NSEC records.

So yes, there is a conflict. But it's not a conflict between two RFCs for the same protocol, it's a conflict between two different protocols. Section 19 in RFC 6762 lists the main differences between DNS and mDNS, and there really are a few significant ones. It does not seem realistic to me to expect to use exactly the same code for both protocols.